# What's the suitable pattern to create a wrapper around the content of the application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, asp.net, user-experience

I want to wrap every next web application with A top menu and right menu like this :

[image]

Every new application should be integrated in this master wrapper.
I thought to create a master page for the wrapper but i will have to create a similar master page for every new application.

---

My question :

What's the suitable pattern to do some thing like that ?

Comment: Look for **portal integration patterns**

Comment: Could you expand on why you would need to '_create a similar master page for every new application_' ?

Comment: @Dan-Cook I don't want the same master page for every application , i want some thing like a one engine and every application will fit in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical variation of the header-body-footer template pattern. There are many ways to implement it.

Have you considered [layouts](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)?

[image]

Uses [razor](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor)

A similar pattern is: [Templating Composit View](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/RSP/Fundamentals/Templating-_Composite_View_Pattern.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot , if the wrapper would be (using razor) , is it possible to integrate (asp.net web form) as the content .i mean one layout (using razor) and many web applications as content(using asp.net web forms)

Comment: Could you clarify the idea please

Answer (score 0):

First, let me clarify that my web experience has been with ASP.Net web pages with Razor and MVC, but in the ASP.Net web pages with Razor projects that I maintain, we use the _SiteLayout.cshtml page to do exactly what you're asking. Similar to this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            @Html.Raw(Configuration.Sidebar)
        </ul>
    </div>
```

for the sidebar (ours is to the left, but you can tweak the layout to get it on the right).
We also use a nav section for menus at the top:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="~/Section/Admin">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Section/Create">Create</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Section/Search>Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Section/Reports">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And after that, inject the body:

```
<div id="body">
    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
</div>
```